# Facing urlencoding issue while processing request

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, get, urlencode

I've written a script in python to scrape some information from a webpage. The site requires `get` request method. The issue I'm facing at this moment is that as the `parameters` is needed to be merged with `url` so it should properly be `urlencoded`. This is where I'm stuck. I can't properly encode it to get a valid response. I gave a try but it doesn't bring any

The script I was trying with:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

fields ={
'/API/api/v1/Search/Properties/?f':'319 lizzie','ty':'2018','pvty':'2017','pn':'1','st':'9','so':'1','pt':'RP;PP;MH;NR','take':'20','skip':'0','page':'1','pageSize':'20'
}
payload = urllib.parse.quote_plus(fields, safe='', encoding=None, errors=None)

headers={
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"
}

page = requests.get("http://search.wcad.org/Proxy/APIProxy.ashx?", params=payload, headers=headers)
print(page.json())
```

The above URL should look like this:

```
http://search.wcad.org/Proxy/APIProxy.ashx?/API/api/v1/Search/Properties/?f=319%20LIZZIE&ty=2018&pvty=2017&pn=1&st=9&so=1&pt=RP%3BPP%3BMH%3BNR&take=20&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=20
```

to get the response.

Btw, this is the error I'm having with my existing script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Social.py", line 9, in <module>
    payload = urllib.parse.quote_plus(fields, safe='', encoding=None, errors=None)
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 728, in quote_plus
    string = quote(string, safe + space, encoding, errors)
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 712, in quote
    return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 737, in quote_from_bytes
    raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

Comment: You needn't to manually concatenate your params. Just put a dictionary into `params`. `requests.get(url, params=<your params' dict>)`.

Comment: @Sraw, I did it in the first place before posting this question. In fact I checked with `page.url` to find out which `url` my script produces. When I found that it was producing the wrong url then i came up with this above try. Everything is above there so don't give any hypothetical solution please.

Comment: Just give us the whole url you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. As [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) indicates, there is no need to do any URL encoding yourself.

The point is that the query string begins at the last question mark, not at the first. Including the second question mark in the URL is mandatory, as `requests` does only adds one when there isn't one there already.

```
import requests

url = "http://search.wcad.org/Proxy/APIProxy.ashx?/API/api/v1/Search/Properties/?"
params = {'f':'319 lizzie','ty':'2018','pvty':'2017','pn':'1','st':'9','so':'1','pt':'RP;PP;MH;NR','take':'20','skip':'0','page':'1','pageSize':'20'}

response = requests.get(url, params)

response.json()
```

results in

```
{
    'ResultList': [{
        'PropertyQuickRefID': 'R016698',
        'PartyQuickRefID': 'O0485204',
        'OwnerQuickRefID': 'R016698',
        'LegacyID': None,
        'PropertyNumber': 'R-13-0410-0620-50000',
        'OwnerName': 'GOOCH, PHILIP L',
        'SitusAddress': '319 LIZZIE ST, TAYLOR, TX  76574',
        'PropertyValue': 46785.0,
        'LegalDescription': 'DOAK ADDITION, BLOCK 62, LOT 5',
        'NeighborhoodCode': 'T541',
        'Abstract': None,
        'Subdivision': 'S3564 - Doak Addition',
        'PropertyType': 'Real',
        'ID': 0,
        'Text': None,
        'TaxYear': 2018,
        'PropertyValueTaxYear': 2017
    }],
    'HasMoreData': False,
    'TotalPageCount': 1,
    'CurrentPage': 1,
    'RecordCount': 1,
    'SearchText': '319 lizzie',
    'PagingHandledByCaller': False,
    'TaxYear': 2018,
    'PropertyValueTaxYear': 0
}
```

Comment: I'm very unhappy that I could not upvote your solution million times. It's indeed a great relief. Thanks a trillion.